# How to change xamforms.control.calendar language?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, plugins

i am using this calendar plugin for my xamarin forms app :

https://github.com/lubiepomaranczki/XamForms.Controls.Calendar

Is there any way i can change the language of this calendar ? ( I want to put it in french )

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried just changing the language of your device?  I'd assume that it uses standard .NET i8n features

Comment: Good question, how do i do that ? ( i'm kinda new to this ) thanks

Comment: In the device settings.  Google it.  I don’t know what kind of device you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test the code in the Github.

The original language:

[image]

Set the code in MainActivity:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
```

The screenshot:

[image]